# Need help in passing data from tableView to another viewController Swift. Keep having error after looking through other examples

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

```
var passValue:String!
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var indexPath1 = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath1!)
    passValue = (cell?.textLabel?.text)!
    print(passValue)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pushy", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pushy"
    {
      var viewController1 = segue.destinationViewController as! home

      viewController1.nameLbl.text = passValue// This is the error highlighted
      self.presentViewController(viewController1, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I keep having error; fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `NSindexPath` when `tableView(didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` already provides you with one? And what does `print(passValue)` print?

Comment: @JacobsonTalom maybe I should delete that away. I looked it up on some other examples. print(passValue) prints the cell textLabel. I am just unable to pass the cell textLabel onto another viewController

Comment: In the debug area, in the left panel, which variable shows up as `nil`? You're probably testing things out but still try to use implicit unwrapping as less as possible. It causes problems like you have right now.

Comment: it says passValue=(String!) nil. Before implementing prepareForSegue passValue has its values. If i were to block the codes out, the values are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure value of viewController1 and nameLbl  not nil ! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the passValue is nil. Since it is an implicitly unwrapped optional as denoted by the `!`, when the value was to be used the computer couldn't find it and thus crashed. `(cell?.textLabel?.text)!` is therefore nil in your example. Perhaps try this...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell identifier")
passValue = cell?.textLabel?.text
print(passValue)
performSegueWithIdentifier("pushy", sender: self)
}
```

You then can set the cell's identifier in the storyboard

Comment: If `passValue` was `nil`, it should have been crashed at `print(passValue)` though.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that, thank you for pointing that out @Jacobson Talom. Neglect my answer.